# Drupal 6 mail to multiple recipients (modifying $to variable)

Tags: email, drupal, drupal-6

I used the drupal example email module (email_example) found here: http://drupal.org/project/examples

I'd like to email multiple recipients and according to http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!mail.inc/function/drupal_mail/6:

$to: The e-mail address or addresses where the message will be sent to. The formatting of this string must comply with RFC 2822. Some examples are: user@example.com user@example.com, anotheruser@example.com User  User , Another User

HOWEVER. When I try to modify $to in function email_example_mail_send($form_values) {

**I am not able to add multiple addresses.**

either

```
 $to = "example@place.com";
 $to = $form_values['email1'];
```

work,

but

```
$to = "example@place.com", "other@place.com";
```

or

```
$to = $form_values['email1'], $form_values['email2'] ;
```

do not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your strings aren't properly formatted. What you need is something like this:

```
$to = $form_values['email1'] . ', ' . $form_values['email2'];
```

That will place the comma separated email addresses into $to.